# Conditional Format Code From Record Macro Causes Error

Tags: excel, vba, format, conditional-formatting

The code generated from record macro to conditional format a column doesn't work. The code in asterisk below is what prompts the error.

```
Worksheets("Characterisation").Select
    Columns("D:D").Select
     **Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
    xlConditionValueLowestValue**
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
    .Color = 7039480
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
    xlConditionValuePercentile
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
    .Color = 8711167
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
    xlConditionValueHighestValue
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
    .Color = 8109667
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: what error does it give

Comment: If `Selection.FormatConditions(1)` throws an error then you should check whether the selection contains format conditions already. If not, then you must add one at first. Btw.: you should mentione **which** error is thrown. And you should avoid using `Select` and working with the `Selection`. You should using object variables instead.

Comment: The rest of my code is for moving rows to another sheet which disrupts the formatting so on the row that is moved there is no initial format, will this be a problem? The error is "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Not fully answerable with this informations only. But somewhere in your recorded macro must be `Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=...`. This adds a color scale format condition to the selection and this lacks now.

Comment: @Tom does your code need to add a new Conditinal Formatting? or just modify an existing one ?

Comment: The formatting is already applied on the column but is not appearing on the newly inserted row so it might be best if I can just extend the formatting to the new row rather or delete the old format and replace it each time

Comment: I've had a look at the formats of the column once a few rows are copied over and it appears to copy the formatting but only to that one cell so the colour gradient format will not change gradient as they all have a format non-relative to one another.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code below and it runs without errors in the tests I conducted on my Excel Worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CondFormatting()

With Worksheets("Characterisation")
    ' add the new type of Conditional Formatting
    .Columns("D:D").FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3

    With .Columns("D:D")                           
        With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1)
            .Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
            .FormatColor.Color = 7039480
            .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
        End With

        With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2)
            .Type = xlConditionValuePercentile
            .Value = 50
            .FormatColor.Color = 8711167
            .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
        End With

        With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3)
            .Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
            .FormatColor.Color = 8109667
            .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
        End With        
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is still throwing up the same error with the line `With .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1)`. I imagine there is a problem with the rest of my code or because I already need formatting in the column that reapplying it doesn't work.

Comment: @Tom can you post the rest of your code (relevant section), maybe you are changing something that causes this error ?

Comment: @Tom try edited code - added the creation of the Conditional Formatting type `.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.

@Shai I've been playing around to try and get a better result, so far my code for formatting and filter are like below, the filter should bring the 'VIP' rows to the top followed by 1, 2, 3...

```
With Worksheets("Burn")
     Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
Selection.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
    xlConditionValueLowestValue
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
    .Color = 7039480
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
    xlConditionValuePercentile
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
    .Color = 8711167
    .TintAndShade = 0

End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
    xlConditionValueHighestValue
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
    .Color = 8109667
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:="VIP", _
    TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Bold = True
    .Italic = False
    .Color = -16711681
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Burn").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Burn").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("D14"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Burn").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Burn").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Burn").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add( _
    Range("D14"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue. _
    Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Burn").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End With
```

And this is the code I am using to create a higher value for the new rows unless assigned with 'VIP' or blank:

```
If IsNumeric("D15") Then
    MaxVal1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(wk2.Range("D15:D1000"))
    Range("D15").Value = MaxVal1 + 1

    End If
```